# C++ Visual Studio Error: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name (DirectX 11)

Tags: c++, directx-11

I dont understand what's wrong here

manager.h

```
#pragma once
class CManager
{

public:
static void Init();
static void Uninit();
static void Update();
static void Draw();

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
#include "manager.h"

...

CManager::Init(); //error here 

...

CManager::Update(); //error here


CManager::Draw(); //and here
```

But name followed by :: is already a class. Why does it show me an error?

Comment: Tip: `CManager::Init();` by itself doesn't mean anything. That's a call to a function that doesn't exist. Are you trying to define them? If so it should be `void CManager::Init() { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to call your functions, didn't you?
If I'm right, then you need first define your functions, before you can call them.

```
class CManager
{

public:
    static void Init();
    static void Uninit();
    static void Update();
    static void Draw();

};
```

Here you only **declared** them.

You have to **define** them, either inside your class:

```
class CManager
{

public:
    static void Init()
    {
        //Do something...
    }
    static void Uninit()
    {
        //...
    }
    static void Update()
    {
        //...
    }
    static void Draw()
    {
        //...
    }

};
```

... or outside your class:

```
void CManager::Init()
{
    //Do something...
}
//and so on...
```